# Access 2013 Sub form is not loading unless I use the table instead of my query

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have upgraded from access 2010 adp to 2013 accdb  and encountered several challenges.  I have a Main Form that has one Sub Form.  The Form is coded to allow either new records or bring up all the current records.  They are linked by the Primary Key from the Main Form. The sub form is based on a query, but the form won't display if I use the query.  The query is updatable.  When I switch the recordsource to the table, it displays, but I am not sure it's properly linked.  I say that because I have a CBO that won't display any data which is linked to a field on the main form.  Works fine is sql, but not in the form.  It all worked, of curse, in access 2010.

If Forms!FrmRequest.NewRecord = True Then
reset_unbound
cmdEmail.Enabled = True

```
Forms!FrmRequest!SfrmReqeust.Visible = True
```

Once the Main Form information is entered and the PK is created, the Subform has a one to many relationship (table used by main form and table used by subform).  My theory is that because the table and query are linked to the backend (SQL Server), the keys aren't getting updated to link the new recordset.  If this is the case, how do I programmatically relink the table/query?

Answer (score 0):

did you set the link master and child settings correct?

this one:

[image]

So, by setting the above, then the sub form will only show correct related records.

However, in code, if you shove in, and set the data source of the sub form, then sometimes the above two link master and child settings can be lost.

but, as long as the correct so called foreign key value in part of and included in your query? Then you should freely be able to base that sub form on a query, or a directly to a linked table.

And note that ZERO code is required to set the FK value if you use the above, and this includes linked tables to SQL server.

So, access will set, and insert the FK value for you, but you have to tell access what column is to be used for linking up the relationships.

With above, then if you filter or load the main form to ONE record, then the sub form should correctly show only the correct child reocrds.

and if you add a new row to the sub form, it will insert and set the FK  value for you automatic without code.

Comment: Yes, the forms are linked.  These forms were created along with several others in the previous version on the database which was Access 2010 adp.  None of the subforms/subreports function properly even though they have the proper master and child fields linked.  If a table is used, which can't always be done, the form/report shows up.  Doesn't make any sense to me.   The forms code checks to see if your creating a new record or bringing up previously entered ones.  If the subform isn't displaying, I can't enter new data in the child record.